# Quantum Gradient caculation

Tags: partial-derivative, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I'm studying the quantum mechanics and reading a paper named "Barren plateaus in quantum neural network training landscape." In the paper, the author calculates the gradient of the objective function. I'm a newbie in quantum mechanics and want to know the process to get the gradient of the objective function, which is in Dirac notation.

Here is the information from the paper (Eq. 1~3)

$U(\theta) = U(\theta_1, ..., \theta_L) =\prod_{l=1}^L U_l(\theta_l)W_l$

where

$ U(\theta) =exp(-i\theta_l V_l)$

and the objective function $E(\theta)$ expressed as the expectation value over Hermitian operator $H$

$E(\theta) =i\langle{0|U(\theta)^\dagger H U(\theta)|0\rangle}$

In the last equation, the paper says that the gradient of the objective function takes the simple form as

$\partial_k E = i\langle0|U^\dagger_{\_}[V_k, U^\dagger_{+}HU_{+}]U_{-}|0\rangle$

where $U_{-} = \prod^{k-1}_{l=o}U_l(\theta_l)W_l$

and

$U_{+} = \prod^{L}_{l=k}U_l(\theta_l)W_l$

In the equation, I can't catch the process of calculating the partial derivatives

Is there any reference for calculating the gradient of dirac notation process for me?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the partial derivatives of $U(\theta)$ first ? Next step would be a product rule on $E(\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your advice and Get the -i and even can't reach the gradient of the objective function...

Comment: Hello @JERMY , you have probably learned this at this point. However, just in case you have not. I suggest utilizing the Hellmann-Feynman theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem#:~:text=In%20quantum%20mechanics%2C%20the%20Hellmann,respect%20to%20that%20same%20parameter.